# Pressing hidden button after focus on textbox

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

In this URL: https://list.tmall.com/search_product.htm?q=%B3%E8%CE%EF%CA%B3%C6%B7&type=p&vmarket=&spm=875.7931836%2FB.a2227oh.d100&from=mallfp..pc_1_searchbutton

I'm trying to press the submit button on a form, but it only appears after focusing on either the start_price textbox or the end_price one.

So Far I've tried the following:

```
    WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.NAME, "start_price"))).send_keys(i)
    WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.NAME, "end_price"))).send_keys(i)
    WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "J_FPEnter"))).click()
```

but it doesn't appear to be working.
The desired output would be to redirect to a URL like this:
https://list.tmall.com/search_product.htm?start_price=1&end_price=1&search_condition=48&sort=s&style=g&from=mallfp..pc_1_searchbutton&q=%B3%E8%CE%EF%CA%B3%C6%B7&shopType=any

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to click first before send a text, and I suggest to use `element_to_be_clickable` instead of `presence_of_element_located`

```
start_price = WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(EC. element_to_be_clickable((By.NAME, "start_price")))
start_price.click()
start_price.send_keys(i)
end_price = WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.NAME, "end_price")))
end_price.click()
end_price.send_keys(i)
WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "J_FPEnter"))).click()
```